# New services slowing boot after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, xubuntu

I have upgrade my Xubuntu 16.04 to Xubuntu 18.04 via the internal updater; it took a while but appears complete and stable. (I am a middling ability user in terms of Linux and tech.) But boot time has increased over the old installation, and has elevated entries such as UFW to be one of the main culprits in slowing startup. The worst offenders from the top of systemd-analyze are as follows:

```
Startup finished in 5.219s (kernel) + 29.404s (userspace) = 34.623s

$ systemd-analyze blame
     13.213s systemd-journal-flush.service
     12.415s dev-sda5.device
     11.167s ufw.service
      9.136s systemd-udevd.service
      6.724s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      3.386s ModemManager.service
      3.274s accounts-daemon.service
      2.300s udisks2.service
      2.228s NetworkManager.service
      2.200s apport.service
      2.178s systemd-logind.service
      2.174s snapd.service
      2.160s gpu-manager.service
      2.151s networkd-dispatcher.service
      2.148s speech-dispatcher.service
      2.146s alsa-restore.service
      2.143s lm-sensors.service
      2.131s pppd-dns.service

Desktop
CPU = AMD A8-5600K APU with Radeon(tm) Graphics
RAM = 8Gb
```

I have already correct/edited the apt-daily.service problem out of the picture (to delay it by x minutes). The journal-flush.service never figured in 16.04, and the journal is about 5kb in size, so I have no idea what it is doing and why. Likewise, UFW never used to appear at this point in the startup, and again I cannot see what it is doing. Both services are using default settings.

Maybe I'm being impatient, but any insights would be welcome.